# Grep for last X hours

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging, grep

I have a log file. Each line is prepended with a date and the date format is as below:

```
2016-02-01 11:34:48,567.......
```

How do I `grep` this file for last 24 hours?

I tried few things such as below for specific time but this approach wont work for last X hours:

```
grep "2016-02-01 15:0[1-9]:00 logfile
```

Also, the following does work for -1hour but fails for -23 or -24hours:

```
 grep "^$(date -d -23hour +'%Y-%m-%d %H')" logfile
```

Comment: date -d -1day +'%Y-%m-%d %H'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` if lines are arranged in chronological order.

```
sed -e "1,/^$(date -d -23hour +'%Y-%m-%d %H')/d"
```

This will delete all lines until the first match is found ie print all line after the first match till the end of file.

Comment: This assumes the log file gets at least one hit per hour.

Comment: Yeah. Else we need regex in place of fixed date string.